# Is there any strange bug in posting or is it just someone joking?

Tags: discussion, posting

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139589/how-to-get-total-records-count-of-posts-for-particular-date-in-facebook-api and [How to get total records count of posts for particular date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139574/how-to-get-total-records-count-of-posts-for-particular-date) were posted in a VERY SHORT timestamp, each one from another account; both the questions are exact duplicates of each other.

- [first 13:22:39](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8139589/764846)
- [second 13:23:14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139574/how-to-get-total-records-count-of-posts-for-particular-date)

Is it a bug?

Comment: Maybe they both just got out of class and it's a homework assignment =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that these are both "new" user accounts, I'm guessing it was more of a spam type action than anything else.